# Filling a div with image using jQuery only works 2nd time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I'm using a block of jQuery to fill a div with an image when a user selects from an input field, so they can see what they're uploading before they upload. It also adds HTML to another div with the width and height of the image.
The only problem is that it doesn't work the first time you select an image; you have to click Browse a second time, select the image again, and then it shows.
Any ideas what's going on?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('input#photo').on('change', function() {
                    var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
                    if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) return; // no file selected, or no FileReader support
                    if (/^image/.test(files[0].type)) {  // only image file
                        var image = new Image();
                        var reader = new FileReader();   
                        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);  
                        reader.onloadend = function(e) {  
                            image.src = e.target.result;
                            image.onload = function() {
                            }
                            $('div#image-preview').css('width', image.width);
                            $('div#image-preview').css('height', image.height);
                            $('div#image-preview').css('background-image', 'url(' + this.result + ')');
                            $('div#image-preview').css('display', 'inline-block');
                            $('div#file-width-height').empty();
                            $('div#file-width-height').append('width: ' + image.width + ' height: ' + image.height);
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            });
```

The first time an image is selected, width and height are set to zero.

Comment: Please add a Markup or FIDDLE to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that what you want is more like this:

```
image.onload = function() {
   /* do these in the onload function... */
   $('div#image-preview').css('width', image.width);
   $('div#image-preview').css('height', image.height);
   $('div#image-preview').css('background-image', 'url(' + this.result + ')');
   $('div#image-preview').css('display', 'inline-block');
   $('div#file-width-height').empty();
   $('div#file-width-height').append('width: ' + image.width + ' height: ' + image.height);
}
```

Comment: You could chain the functions like so: `$('div#image-preview').css({'width':image.width,'height', image.height,'background-image':'url(' + this.result + ')','display':'inline-block'});
$('div#file-width-height').empty().append('width: ' + image.width + ' height: ' + image.height);`

Comment: Doing this, and changing "this.result" to "e.target.result" fixed the problem =)

Comment: Yes, the this there isn't the this you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

add this function

```
  $('input#photo').on('change', function() {

                var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
                if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) return; // no file selected, or no FileReader support
                if (/^image/.test(files[0].type)) {  // only image file
                    var image = new Image();
                    var reader = new FileReader();   
                    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);  
                    reader.onloadend = function(e) {  
                        image.src = e.target.result;
                        $('div#image-preview').css('background-image', 'url(' + this.result + ')');
                        image.onload = function() {
                        $('div#image-preview').css('width', image.width);
                        $('div#image-preview').css('height', image.height);

                        $('div#image-preview').css('display', 'inline-block');
                        $('div#file-width-height').empty();
                        $('div#file-width-height').append('width: ' + image.width + ' height: ' + image.height);}

                    }
                }
                return false;
            });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0pL6hn0p/6/

Answer (score 0):

Adding the code to the image.onload function and changing "this.result" to "e.target.result" fixed the problem.

```
image.onload = function() {
    $('div#image-preview').css('width', image.width);
    $('div#image-preview').css('height', image.height);
    $('div#image-preview').css('background-image', 'url(' + e.target.result + ')');
    $('div#image-preview').css('display', 'inline-block');
    $('div#file-width-height').empty();
    $('div#file-width-height').append('width: ' + image.width + ' height: ' + image.height); 
}
```